# work problem help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

[image]

from this table I am suppose to work out which mine can produce the greatest amount of electricity before it runs out of coal.

not sure how to go about calculating this?

Comment: Can you calculate number of kilograms remaining?

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply units of electricity per kilogram by millions of tonnes of coal, you get the number of billions of units of electricity that can be produced.  (U.S. billions, that is, $10^9.$)  For the Folen mine, for example, we get $17.0\times68.27 = 1160.59$ billion units.  Just do this calculation for each mine and see which gives the largest product.